# Find a cyclic group in size 6 in $S_5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

I have the following question :

Find a cyclic group in size 6 in $S_5$.

Meaning $H=\langle f_1,f_1^2,f_1^3,f_1^4,f_1^5,f_1^6=e\rangle$

I wonder if there's a method to solving such questions.

I know that $f_1^6=e$, My question is more general assuming I need to find a cyclic group in size $1,2,3,..$ in $S_5$ should I just "test" until I find the right one I wonder if there's a smarter method to solve these kind of questions.

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that $C_6 \cong C_2 \times C_3$ (here $C_k$ denotes the cyclic group of order $k$). Now, $(12)$ is a $2$-cycle (it has order $2$), $(345)$ has order $3$, so they generate two (commuting and trivially intersecting) subgroups of order $2,3$, and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cyclic subgroup generated by $(1 2)(3 4 5)$ has order $lcm(2,3)=6$.

Comment: So generally speaking if I need to find a cyclic subgroup from size $x$ I need to create $(x_1x_2,..)(y_1y_2..)$ so that lcm=$x$?

Comment: Yes, this is a good technique for finding cyclic subgroups of a given order.

Comment: @JaVaPG Yes... **but** the cycles **must** be disjoint, otherwise the order won't likely be the l.c.m.

Comment: JaVaPG: not necessarily two cycles, you can take any finite number of cycles in the generating set, provided any two of these cycles must be disjoint and the LCM of their lengths is the desire size $x$.